# Application Keyboard Shortcut not overriding

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, copy-paste

I want to always paste text without its format. Many applications, like Numbers in my case, have a shortcut for that being `shift+alt+command+v`. Now, that's pretty many keys to press at once so I wanted to override that with a custom keyboard shortcut as suggested in [this answer](http://ask.metafilter.com/187733/OSX-How-to-copy-plaintext-always-everywhere-without-exception).

[image: settings pane]
[sorry for German language, please assume that the shortcuts' names are correct]

I flipped *Paste*'s and *Paste and match style*'s keyboard commands.
Since that did not do it, I also added shortcuts for Numbers individually.

This is what Numbers' *Edit* pane shows:

[image: Numbers' *Edit* pane]

Again, sorry for German language. the first one reads "Paste" and second reads "Paste and match style". The keyboard commands are still the wrong way.

I have restarted Numbers a number (no pun intended) of times but that didn't help. For other applications it doesn't work either.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?
Thanks in advance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the exact name of the menu item. It looks like you're using "Einfügen" but Numbers' menu item uses the synonym "Einsetzen". Correcting that should fix it.